# Weblogic + Hibernate Error: javax.persistence.JoinTable.indexes()[Ljavax/persistence/Index

Tags: java, hibernate, weblogic, jpa-2.1

I'm migrating a project that was running on Tomcat 8 to Weblogic.
I am using Hibernate + JPA 2. When I deploy in weblogic got the following error:

```
Failure occurred in the execution of deployment request with ID "26012160125422" for task "114". Error is: "weblogic.application.ModuleException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.persistence.JoinTable.indexes()[Ljavax/persistence/Index;"
```

weblogic.application.ModuleException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.persistence.JoinTable.indexes()[Ljavax/persistence/Index

Environment 
- Java: jdk1.8.0_60 
- Weblogic: 12.1.3 
- hibernate-entitymanager: 4.3.1.Final 
- hibernate-core: 4.3.1.Final 
- javaee-api: 7.0

pom.xml

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
        <version>7.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>        
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.1.Final</version>         
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
        <artifactId>sqljdbc4</artifactId>
        <version>4.0</version>
    </dependency>    
</dependencies>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is strange that you use `javaee-api-7.0.jar`, Hibernate 4 has `hibernate-jpa-2.1-api-1.0.0.Final.jar` as a dependency. But it is not a reason of the error.

`JoinTable.indexes()` was added with `Java Persistence 2.1`. So you just have an old jar with `JoinTable` annotation in the classpath (in the Weblogic default lib folders).

To check where is this jar, run this code before the Hibernate configuration code

```
URL joinTableUrl = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader()
    .getResource(
    "javax/persistence/JoinTable.class");
System.out.println(joinTableUrl);
```

To check `JoinTable` has `indexes()` method

```
Class<?> joinTable = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader()
        .loadClass(JoinTable.class.getName());

System.out.println(Arrays.asList(joinTable.getDeclaredMethods()));
```